# Differentiate between mouse and keyboard triggering onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, mouseevent, keypress

I need to find a way to determine if a link has been activated via a mouse click or a keypress.

```
<a href="" onclick="submitData(event, '2011-07-04')">Save</a>
```

The idea is that if they are using a mouse to hit the link then they can keep using the mouse to choose what they do next. But if they tabbing around the page and they tab to the Save link, then I'll open then next line for editing (the page is like a spreadsheet with each line becoming editable using ajax).

I thought the event parameter could be queried for which mouse button is pressed, but when no button is pressed the answer is 0 and that's the same as the left mouse button. They I thought I could get the keyCode from the event but that is coming back as undefined so I'm assuming a mouse event doesn't include that info.

```
function submitData(event, id)
{
    alert("key = "+event.keyCode + "  mouse button = "+event.button);
}
```

always returns "key = undefined  mouse button = 0"

Can you help?

Comment: This strategy makes no sense at all. Just because a mouse click is used for one interaction doesn't mean the user wants to use a mouse for all interaction, the same for keyboard events. And why use a link that behaves like a button?

Comment: Both those choices are above my paygrade, though I do understand  the first. The idea is that certain power users, of which there are very few, will want to edit every row on the page, much like a spreadsheet, and they won't like having to switch from keyboard to mouse and back. Other users will only want to edit one row and then leave. If the following row became editable fields after they had finished editing the one they chose, they'd get distracted and maybe edit that one too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a condition with `event.type`

```
function submitData(event, id)
{
    if(event.type == 'mousedown')
    {
        // do something
        return;
    }
    if(event.type == 'keypress')
    {
        // do something else
        return;
    }
}
```

Note: You'll need to attach an event which supports both event types. With JQuery it would look something like `$('a.save').bind('mousedown keypress', submitData(event, this));`

The inline `onClick=""` will not help you as it will always pass that click event since that's how it's trapped.

**EDIT**: **Here's a working demo** to prove my case with native JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/HPEjt/

I used a button so it'd be easier to see the node highlighted during a tab focus, but it will work the same with any node.

Comment: I'm seeing an `event.type` of "click" in both cases.

Comment: This worked for me. Since the save button only gets rendered if the row has become editable I'll look into jQuery Live for hooking up the  mousedown and keypress events. Cheers.

Comment: Cool, but this doesn't really answer the question. A mousedown is not a click. This is a workaround that perverts the meaning of a click, which is a mousedown followed by a mouseup on the same element. Gonzalo's solution preserves the meaning of the concept.

Comment: It doesn't take "click" behavior into account. A click is mouse down and mouse up on same item, handling also long touch or drag touch on touch-sensitive devices, handling also various keyboard "clicks".

Comment: `mousedown` is not the same as `click` (although it may be close enough in some situations)

Answer (score 23):

Could check if [`event.screenX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/screenX) and `event.screenY` are zero.

```
$('a#foo').click(function(evt) {
  if (evt.screenX == 0 && evt.screenY == 0) {
    window.alert('Keyboard click.');
  } else {
    window.alert('Mouse click.');
  }
});
```

[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/wernight/pen/dGmBxq?editors=1011)

I couldn't find a guarantee that it works in all browsers and all cases, but it has the benefit of not trying to detect a "click" done via the keyboard. So this solution **detects "click" more reliably at the cost of detecting if it's from keyboard or mouse somewhat less reliably**. If you prefer the *reverse*, look as the [answer from @Gonzalo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7465044/167897).

Note: One place I found using this method is [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/reference_builds/chrome_linux/+/3c1359e615f07b066b00fa5eb0f7dfe65276578b%5E!/)

Comment: Clever. This is the only working solution on the page as of Sep 2018

Comment: Doesn't work in Safari, though. Safari defaults the screen coordinates to the center of the target element. :(

Comment: I had used this method too, but after @CraigKovatch's comment about Safari I noticed that that's indeed the case: it doesn't work on Safari (v13.1.1).

Comment: As of 2022, this is still the only working solution. At least in this thread. All ENTER, ARROW DOWN, and MOUSE CLICK events trigger the same `evt.type` value of `click`.

Answer (score 15):

You can use event.detail

```
if(event.detail === 0) {
    // keypress
} else {
    // mouse event
}
```

Comment: almost perfect. Doesn't work for Bootstrap 4 radio buttons, as when the active radio button is Mouse-clicked twice, **two** events are triggered (one for the aesthetic button label, and one for the input radio button behind). The first one (for <label>) returns `event.detail === 1` as expected, but the second one (for <input radio>) return `event.detail === 0`, probably because Bootstrap is handling the change in background. +1 for promising answer, and it'll work in most cases :)

Comment: @Prid maybe you can figure out a workaround using `event.stopPropagation`? I'm not sure whether the label always fires even when you click directly on the radio button.

Comment: IE11 event.detail is 0 for both mouse and keyboard click events :(

Answer (score 5):

You can differentiate between a click and a keyboard hit capturing and discarding the keydown event originated at the moment of the key press:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("a#foo").keydown(function() {
        alert("keyboard");
        return false;
    }).click(function() {
        alert("mouse");
        return false;
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NuP2g/

Comment: +1 Excellent! This is not just the most elegant answer, but really the *only* actual working answer to the question that preserves the meaning of the "click" concept. The other answers switch out click (the original question) for either mousedown or mouseup, which are only part of a click. Nobody wants a mouseup that began as a mousedown on a different element to be handled as a click. Nice!

Comment: There are various ways to "click" from keyboard. Usually its [ctrl+][alt+]enter but many of those open in a new tab so that should remain consistent, and sometimes other keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: This doesn't work with "Enter" key. It fires both events sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following

```
const isKeyboardClick = nativeEvent.detail === 0 && !nativeEvent.pointerType;
```

Works in evergreen browsers via `detail` and IE11 via `pointerType`. Does not work for the case where e.g. radio button `<input>` is wrapped by a `<label>` element.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but given how much time I lost looking for a working, no jquery and IE-compatible solution, I think it won't be a bad idea to put it here (where I came first).

I tested this and found it working fine :

```
let mouseDown = false;

element.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  mouseDown = true;
});

element.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  mouseDown = false;
});

element.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  if (mouseDown) {
    // keyboard
  } else {
    // mouse
  }
});
```

Source link : https://www.darrenlester.com/blog/focus-only-on-tab

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't able to come up with solution relying entirely on the events but you can position an anchor tag over a button and give it a `tabindex` of `-1`. This gives you a button that can be focused and engaged with keyboard enter/spacebar, as well as giving you a clickable surface that gives you an option to differentiate the two codepaths.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
}

.anchor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" class="button">
  button
  <a class="anchor" href="#example" tabindex="-1"></a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you can make use of `instanceof` which even has [full browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=instanceof).

```
function onMouseOrKeyboardSubmit(event, id) {
    if (event instanceof KeyboardEvent) {
        alert("Submitted via keyboard");
    } else if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
        alert("Submitted via mouse");
    } else {
        alert("Unexpected submit event");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Handle the `mouseup` event.
If you get a `click` right afterwards, it was *probably* done with the mouse.